# Unable to refresh Ajax data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a script:

```
    <script type="application/javascript">
    var ajax = window.setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: 'data.php',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response){
                var len = response.length;
                $("#getAjax").append("<div id='getAjax2' class='content content-"+len+"'></div>")
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var title = response[i].title;
                    var live = response[i].live;
                    var div_result = "<div class='result'>" +
                "<div class='title'>" + title + "</div>" +
                "<div class='number bnum'>" + live + "</div>" +
                "</div>";

                    $("#getAjax2").append(div_result);
                }

            }
        });
    }, 5000);
    </script>
```

It loads data perfectly only once after page load but doesn't refresh anymore.

What I'm trying is to refresh this data every 5 seconds.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the **response**, for example, contains always the same data, then how will you notice a refresh (visually)?. Anyway, on every **success callback** you are appending a new `div` with `id='getAjax2'` to the element `#getAjax`, and this will result on multiple elements with the same `id`, that is a mistake you can review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Shidersz, your divs have the same ID. Here's a slightly modified version that adds the response to a new div:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var ajax = window.setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: 'data.php',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response){
                var len = response.length;
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                $("#getAjax").append(div).attr('class', "content content-"+len);
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var title = response[i].title;
                    var live = response[i].live;
                    var div_result = "<div class='result'>" +
                        "<div class='title'>" + title + "</div>" +
                        "<div class='number bnum'>" + live + "</div>" +
                        "</div>";

                    $(div).append(div_result);
                }

            }
        });
    }, 5000);
    </script>
```